# How i can i control access of multiple apps in a one Salesforce package, when a customer installed it

Tags: managed-package, licenses

I have multiple apps in a package. I don't want to give access to all apps for selected customers. is there a way I can control which app they can access in the package

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The platform supports a feature licensing mechanism as described in [Manage Features](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/fma_manage_features.htm). This allows you to turn on and off features in your managed package via a Feature Management App (FMA) that sits in the same org as your License Management App (LMA).

So you setup a feature for each of your "apps".

Comment: Thank you very much. this is helpful,    is there any other way other than FMA

Comment: @adityaram Well you could create something of your own e.g. issue tokens to customers that encrypt their org id and some access rights that your package decrypts. Or make a web service call out to your own licensing server or the LMA org itself.

Comment: Thank you for the Information @Keith. Will go with FMA